# Magento 2: Update default value for custom customer attribute programmatically

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, magento-cloud

We have a custom boolean customer attribute created from installSchema script like below:

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
        'test_attribute',
        [
            'label'        => 'Test Attribute',
            'input' => 'select',  
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean', 
            'default' => 0,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
        ]
    );
```

I need to change the default value to "1" for this attribute through upgradeSchema.
Tried below code for the same in upgrade schema:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory->create()->updateAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'test_attribute', 'default', 1);
    }
```

But, it didn't worked. The default value is still No, also verified in eav_attribute table in database. I can also confirm that the upgrade schema is working and the if condition for version compare is also working. The version in setup_module table is also getting updated.
Are there any changes needed to the updateAttribute method call? Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed on using "default_value" instead of "default".
So, the updated working code in upgradeSchema is:

```
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {
    $this->eavSetupFactory->create()->updateAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'test_attribute', 'default_value', 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create **etc/UpgradeData.php**

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;
    
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

    
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    )
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        //check version
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '2.0.3') < 0) {

            //update customer attribute
            $customerSetup->updateAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'attribute_code',
            'default',
            1
        );
        }

    }
}
```